# Как заставить функцию scanf_s считать всю строку на русском (!) до знака перевода строки (т.е. все символы и пробелы)?

Tags: c++, c

Возникли две проблемы. Во-первых, scanf_s не может считать в буфер русские символы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во-вторых,

```
printf("\nВведите фамилию и инициалы: ");
scanf_s("%s", buff, (unsigned)_countof(buff));
```

просит ввод фамилии и инициалов, между которыми должен быть пробел. Но scanf_s считает строку только до пробела. Много гуглил, но так и не смог найти решение!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string NAME;
    int GROUP;
    int SES[5];
};


int main()

{

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

const int n = 10;

char buff[255];
Student STUD1[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Введите данные для %i-го студента:\n", i + 1);

    printf("\nВведите фамилию и инициалы: ");
    scanf_s("%s", buff, (unsigned)_countof(buff));
    STUD1[i].NAME = string(buff);
    printf("\nВведите номер группы : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &STUD1[i].GROUP);
    printf("\nВведите успеваемость студента: ");
    scanf_s("%d%d%d%d%d", &STUD1[i].SES[0], &STUD1[i].SES[1], &STUD1[i].SES[2], &STUD1[i].SES[3], &STUD1[i].SES[4]);
}

printf("----------------------------------------\n");

bool key;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    key = true;
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        if (STUD1[i].SES[x] < 4) key = false;
    }
    if (key) {
        strcpy_s(buff, STUD1[i].NAME.c_str());
        printf("Студент %s, группа %i", buff, STUD1[i].GROUP);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Вы сами написали "%s". А это ровно и значит "до пробела". Во вторых, используйте соответствующие функции, например, getline

Comment: @KoVadim Извините, забыл уточнить, нужно использовать именно scanf_s (scanf).
**_А это ровно и значит "до пробела"_** странно, в моём пособии ничего об этом не сказано. А как тогда мне быть?

Comment: можно написать как то так `char data[100]; scanf("%99[^\n]", data);` Но пособие лучше выкинуть, оно видимо учит плохому.

Answer (score 2):

Знак `"%255s"` в функции `scanf` означает читать строку **до** *пробела* или до разрешённого количества букв 255. А это значит оно будет читать **одно** слово.

Есть в функции `scanf` возможность читать строку **до** определённых символов.

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main  ( ) {
  char  str [ 0x100 ] ;
  int n = scanf ( "%255[^\n\r]" , & ( str [ 0 ] ) ) ;
  printf  ( "n = %d\n" , n ) ;
  printf  ( "str = \"%s\"\n" , & ( str [ 0 ] ) ) ;
}
```

`"%255[^\n\r]"` - означает записывать в строку **все** символы кроме переноса строки. Знаки переноса строки не будут записаны. А пробелы будут.

Comment: всё отлично, но как разобраться с проблемой считывания кириллицы?

Comment: @ashes что за проблема?

Comment: @andreymal пытаюсь сосчитать строку, состоящую из русских букв. scanf_s считывает какую-то ересь, при этом printf выводит на экран нормальную строку из кириллицы

Comment: @ashes, вы имеете в виду вот этот вывод `cout << STUD1[i].NAME;`?

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");` - ничего не делает, так как такой локали нет. Это не ересь, а локаль консоли другая, не та, что вы думаете. Правильную локаль поставьте.

Comment: @AlexGlebe обновил вопрос

Comment: Кажется в винде где-то так : `SetConsoleCP(1251); SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`

Comment: @ashes, это же винда, вам надо настроить консоль (ее ввод и вывод) на ту же кодировку русских букв, что и кодировка русского текста в программе